# Getting JSON results in Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, r-googlesheets

I am struggling to get JSON results from a specific api url into google sheets in tabular format.

I have used code from the below link to import JSON data into Google Spreadsheets by adding a script.
https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

but still I dont get the data properly. I am listing below JSON output. Can someone help me how to show it properly in google sheets in tabular format?

The formula I am using is
`=importjson(B1,"","noInherit, noTruncate")` and cell B1 has the api url which also has a ?apikey.

Thanks

**First link**

```
{  
   "squad":[  
      {  
         "name":"England",
         "players":[  
            {  
               "pid":24598,
               "name":"Eoin Morgan"
            },
            {  
               "pid":351588,
               "name":"Mark Wood"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"Pakistan",
         "players":[  
            {  
               "pid":227760,
               "name":"Sarfraz Ahmed"
            },
            {  
               "pid":43685,
               "name":"Yasir Shah"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "cache":true,
   "v":"1",
   "ttl":7,
   "provider":{  
      "source":"Various",
      "url":"https://cricapi.com/",
      "pubDate":"2019-05-15T16:12:58.268Z"
   },
   "creditsLeft":234
}
```

**Second link**

```
{  
   "dateTimeGMT":"2019-05-14T12:00:00.000Z",
   "data":{  
      "fielding":[  
         {  
            "title":"Fielding for Pakistan Innings",
            "scores":[  
               {  
                  "name":"CR Woakes",
                  "runout":0,
                  "stumped":0,
                  "bowled":2,
                  "lbw":0,
                  "catch":1,
                  "pid":"247235"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"TK Curran",
                  "runout":1,
                  "stumped":0,
                  "bowled":1,
                  "lbw":1,
                  "catch":0,
                  "pid":"550235"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "title":"Fielding for England Innings",
            "scores":[  
               {  
                  "name":"MM Ali",
                  "runout":0,
                  "stumped":0,
                  "bowled":0,
                  "lbw":0,
                  "catch":1,
                  "pid":"8917"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Shaheen Shah Afridi",
                  "runout":1,
                  "stumped":0,
                  "bowled":0,
                  "lbw":0,
                  "catch":0,
                  "pid":"1072470"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "bowling":[  
         {  
            "scores":[  
               {  
                  "6s":1,
                  "4s":9,
                  "0s":28,
                  "Econ":"6.70",
                  "W":"4",
                  "R":"67",
                  "M":"0",
                  "O":"10",
                  "bowler":"CR Woakes",
                  "pid":"247235"
               },
               {  
                  "6s":0,
                  "4s":1,
                  "0s":1,
                  "Econ":"9.00",
                  "W":"0",
                  "R":"9",
                  "M":"0",
                  "O":"1",
                  "bowler":"JL Denly",
                  "pid":"12454"
               }
            ],
            "title":"Bowling To Pakistan Innings"
         },
         {  
            "scores":[  
               {  
                  "6s":3,
                  "4s":5,
                  "0s":24,
                  "Econ":"7.12",
                  "W":"1",
                  "R":"57",
                  "M":"0",
                  "O":"8",
                  "bowler":"Junaid Khan",
                  "pid":"259551"
               },
               {  
                  "6s":0,
                  "4s":1,
                  "0s":0,
                  "Econ":"10.80",
                  "W":"0",
                  "R":"9",
                  "M":"0",
                  "O":"0.5",
                  "bowler":"Asif Ali",
                  "pid":"494230"
               }
            ],
            "title":"Bowling To England Innings"
         }
      ],
      "batting":[  
         {  
            "scores":[  
               {  
                  "dismissal-by":{  
                     "name":"TK Curran",
                     "pid":"550235"
                  },
                  "dismissal":"bowled",
                  "SR":115,
                  "6s":1,
                  "4s":16,
                  "B":131,
                  "R":151,
                  "dismissal-info":" b Curran",
                  "batsman":"Imam-ul-Haq",
                  "pid":"568276"
               },

               {  
                  "dismissal":"not out",
                  "SR":0,
                  "6s":0,
                  "4s":0,
                  "B":0,
                  "R":0,
                  "dismissal-info":"not out",
                  "batsman":"Junaid Khan",
                  "pid":"259551"
               },
               {  
                  "SR":"",
                  "6s":"",
                  "4s":"",
                  "B":"",
                  "R":"",
                  "dismissal-info":"",
                  "detail":"10 (lb 1, w 9)",
                  "batsman":"Extras",
                  "pid":0
               }
            ],
            "title":"Pakistan Innings"
         },
         {  
            "scores":[  
               {  
                  "dismissal-by":{  
                     "name":"MM Ali",
                     "pid":"8917"
                  },
                  "dismissal":"catch",
                  "SR":138,
                  "6s":4,
                  "4s":8,
                  "B":55,
                  "R":76,
                  "dismissal-info":"c Asif Ali b Faheem Ashraf",
                  "batsman":"JJ Roy",
                  "pid":"298438"
               },
               {  
                  "dismissal":"not out",
                  "SR":141,
                  "6s":1,
                  "4s":1,
                  "B":12,
                  "R":17,
                  "dismissal-info":"not out",
                  "batsman":"EJG Morgan (c)",
                  "pid":"24598"
               },
               {  
                  "SR":"",
                  "6s":"",
                  "4s":"",
                  "B":"",
                  "R":"",
                  "dismissal-info":"",
                  "detail":"12 (lb 3, nb 1, w 8)",
                  "batsman":"Extras",
                  "pid":0
               }
            ],
            "title":"England Innings"
         }
      ],
      "team":[  
         {  
            "players":[  
               {  
                  "name":"JJ Roy",
                  "pid":"298438"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"LE Plunkett",
                  "pid":"19264"
               }
            ],
            "name":"England"
         },
         {  
            "players":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Imam-ul-Haq",
                  "pid":"568276"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Junaid Khan",
                  "pid":"259551"
               }
            ],
            "name":"Pakistan"
         }
      ],
      "man-of-the-match":{  
         "name":"JM Bairstow",
         "pid":"297433"
      },
      "toss_winner_team":"England",
      "winner_team":"England",
      "matchStarted":true
   },
   "type":"ODI",
   "cache3":true,
   "creditsLeft":234,
   "v":"1",
   "ttl":8,
   "provider":{  
      "source":"Various",
      "url":"https://cricapi.com/",
      "pubDate":"2019-05-15T16:11:30.279Z"
   }
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: There is nothing in the spreadsheet. Only two cells filled. A1 with the api url which also has a ?apikey. and B1 with the formula =importjson(B1,"","noInherit, noTruncate"). I have mentioned output of the api url in my question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.